# Changing Object-fit cover height

Tags: html, css

Using Object fit, if I set the height to 100vh it works properly, though if I change it to anything else, it no longer remains the correct size but shrinks down to fill the space as the window shrinks.

Is it possible to keep it proportional like at 100vh but to not actually have it take up the full amount of available space? I am ok with portions of the video being clipped off, I just cant seem to figure out how to get this to work.

Basically what I want is that on mobile 100vh is fine, I have text overlay on top of the video so the extra space works. But on large screens, there is too much unused space over this video (another as well on the full site but figure the same methods can be used to fix that also) and I would like to probably shrink it down to closer to 50 to 65% of the total size.

Below is the CSS I am using on the video currently, there is also a link to a live site of the video since I dont believe I can upload that to SO.

https://tsukiyonocm.github.io/test/

```css
#services {
  position: relative;
}

#servicesVid {
  height: 100vh;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question is not very clear but i would recommend using Media queries to apply different styles for different media types/devices.
for example if you want to set a specific style for larger screen devices such as  laptop  you have to use :

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 1400px) {
 //your style for these  devices that have 1400px+ screen width
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I think I might have been making more of this then I should have. I believe I have just been trying to apply a universal fix when just using the media query option would be the more optimal solution.